# Stumped by a simple regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to see if the string `s` contains any of the symbols in a regex. The regex below works fine on [rubular](http://rubular.com/).

```
s = "asd#d"
s =~ /[~!@#$%^&*()]+/
```

But in Ruby 1.9.2, it gives this error message:

```
syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
s = "asd#d"; s =~ /[~!@#$%^&*()]/
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I tried it on rubular mysqlf.  It seemed that only the `#` was matched.  Is that what your rubular showed?

Comment: @junky: For me, using `a$d#d` , `$` and `#` both match on rubular.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually a special case of string interpolation with global and instance variables that most seem not to know about. Since string interpolation also occurs within regex in Ruby, I'll illustrate below with strings (since they provide for an easier example):

```
@foo = "instancefoo"
$foo = "globalfoo"
"#@foo" # => "instancefoo"
"#$foo" # => "globalfoo"
```

Thus you need to escape the `#` to prevent it from being interpolated:

```
/[~!@\#$%^&*()]+/
```

The only way that I know of to create a non-interpolated regex in Ruby is from a string (note *single* quotes):

```
Regexp.new('[~!@#$%^&*()]+')
```

Comment: Gah! You seem to be right! Oh Ruby, why you interpolate my regex?

Comment: That's weird because `$%` is not a valid global variable, so I didn't think interpolation would be invoked.

Comment: @Zabba I updated my answer with a way to create a non-interpolated regexp, though sadly there doesn't seem to be a more concise way à la single quotes for strings.

Comment: @MarkThomas Agreed, and the syntax error doesn't seem to allude to that very well, but `/#$%/` results in a syntax error as well. It seems it just really confuses the parser.

Comment: And fyi, for the `Regexp.new('[~!@#$%^&*()]+')`, double-quotes instead of single-quotes also causes the same error.

Comment: @Zabba Yup, because then you're just interpolating in a normal string `:)`

Comment: For future reference, this is sort of documented behavior in at least one book: http://books.google.ca/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=ruby+global+variable+interpolation&source=bl&ots=fIDnyi9zjG&sig=BqcdRjtCnj3pj-PCtcMYh7UHS18&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ci29T8IJgZOJArLYzewN&ved=0CFoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=ruby%20global%20variable%20interpolation&f=false

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate this behavior in 1.9.3p0. Apparently there is a problem with the '#$' combination. If you escape either it works. If you reverse them it works:

```
s =~ /[~!@$#%^&*()]+/
```

Edit: in Ruby 1.9 `#$` invokes variable interpolation, even when followed by a `%` which is not a valid variable name.

Comment: Hmm. About your update, yes, reversing the two works. How very odd.

Comment: Yeah, I can't explain why it works on rubular even with 1.9.2 selected.

Comment: @MarkThomas Perhaps rubular uses `Regexp.new('...')`? There's no real reason for them to accept interpolation since there are no variables, and if anything it would probably be a security issue as well.

Answer (score -3):

I disagree, you need to escape the $, its the end of string character.

```
s =~ /[~!@#\$%^&*()]/ => 3
```

That is correct.

Comment: Actually, the `#` is what needs to be escaped. The `$` has no special significance here because it is inside a group `[]`.

Comment: Technically, outside of a character class it is end of line (not string). However, it loses any special meaning within the character class.