# Ruby Regexp Interpolation / Character Class / Global Variable Syntax Clash?

Tags: ruby, regex

Why does this error occur?

```
    Regexp.new("[#$]")
    # => SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
    # => Regexp.new("[#$]")
    #              ^
    # (irb):1: unterminated string meets end of file
    #     from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:1:in `<main>'
```

This should describe the subset of strings consisting of either a single `$` or `#`, literally. And, AFAIU [Ruby's Regexp engine](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/re.rdoc), `#` and `$` [don't need to be escaped](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UK) inside a character class even though they're usually metacharacters.

I would guess from the error message that Ruby is trying to interpolate `$` when it's hitting `#` within double-quotes, but...why? Ordering is important. The `$` and `#` characters have multiple overloaded behaviors, so I'm at a loss about what's triggering this.

PS, FYI:

```
    /[#$]/
    # => SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
    /[$#]/
    # => /[$#]/
    Regexp.new '[$#]'
    # => /[$#]/
    Regexp.new '[#$]'
    # => /[#$]/
    Regexp.new "[#$]"
    # => SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stumped by a simple regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493100/stumped-by-a-simple-regex)

Comment: http://books.google.ca/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=ruby+global+variable+interpolation&source=bl&ots=fIDnyi9zjG&sig=BqcdRjtCnj3pj-PCtcMYh7UHS18&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ci29T8IJgZOJArLYzewN&ved=0CFoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=ruby%20global%20variable%20interpolation&f=false

Comment: @muistooshort: yes, you're right: both questions had the same answer.

Comment: I don't blame you for not finding it, searching for `#$` isn't exactly helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not `$`, but `#`, as `#...` is usually used for variable expansion in double quoted strings. Like `"#{x}"`.

But the thing is you can also expand global variables directly using `#$global`, and that explains your problem:

```
$global = "hello"
"#$global"
=> "hello"
```

So the solution is to escape *either* `#` *or* `$`, as this will break the string interpolation state machine out of it's effort to interpret the construct as an interpolation:

```
puts "\#$global"
=> #$global
puts "#\$global"
=> #$global
```

**EDIT**

And just to make it really clear :) The problem is not the `Regexp`, but you are trying to expand a global variable named `$]` when you type `"#$]"`:

```
puts "#$]"
SyntaxError: (irb):22: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
```

To fix it you need to escape something:

```
puts "\#$]"
=> #$]
```

Comment: +1, but couldn't you also solve the problem by swapping the positions of the symbols (i.e. `[$#]`)?  I'm not fluent in Ruby, but according to the docs `#` is treated as a literal unless it's followed by `{`, `$`, or `@`.

Comment: @AlanMoore - Yes that's true, reordering also solves it. The OP also noted this however in his text *"...ordering is important..."*.

Comment: I don't know what that's supposed to mean, but the order of the characters in a character class can't be significant (aside from the ones that have special meanings like `^` and `-`, that is).

Comment: Alan I interpreted it so that the OP already noted that reordering `$` and `#` fixes the problem. However he was still looking for an answer to why the problem was happening. Ordering in a character class is not significant, just like you say (except when you run into this particular problem).